# variadic template with recursive control

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I need a template function that checks if the first value is among those that follow.

---

I thought I would try something like this but it doesn't work

```
template<class T, class U>
bool is_in_set(const T &t, const U &u) {
  return t == u;
}

template<class T, class ...Args>
bool is_in_set(const T &t, Args...args) {
  return false || is_in_set(t, args...);
}
```

It compiles but I got the following warning `warning C4717 : 'is_in_set' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow`

Can anyone help me to fix it and explain me why it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? If it doesn't compile, show the error message. If it runs, but gives the wrong output, show the input and output.

Comment: It compiles but I got a warning which is `warning C4717 : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow`, I tried to run the problem but occurs an overflow

Comment: Thanks, but please add that information to the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

From C++17, you can write this function with a [fold-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), which is simpler than writing a recursive function with a base case.

```
template<class T, class ...Args>
bool is_in_set(T const & t, Args const & ...args) 
{
  return (... || (t == args));
}
```

And now you can call it like this.

```
is_in_set(1, 2, 3, 4);  // false
is_in_set(1, 2, 1, 4);  // true
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KTWchq)

---

Considering your code, you're getting the warning because you have an infinite recursion on this line:

```
return false || is_in_set(t, args...);  // infinite recursion here
```

Note that you're calling the function template recursively with exactly the same arguments. This means you'll recurse infinitely, and never reach the base case.

You can fix this by naming the second argument and taking the remaining arguments as a parameter pack.

```
template<class T, class U>
bool is_in_set(T const & t, U const &u) 
{
    return t == u;
}
  
template<class T, class U, class ...Args>
bool is_in_set(T const & t, U const & u, Args const &...args) 
{ 
  return is_in_set(t, u) || is_in_set(t, args...);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WjPbWE)

Comment: I m in c++14 on visual studio

Comment: @Linus Yes, I just saw that, as I was editing the tags, so I might update the answer. May I ask why you are still using that standard? Is there any external constraint? If not, just update your compiler.

Comment: Really there is no reason, it was the default setting, I do not know so much about the difference of the standard, I ll try it

Comment: I can t believe it works, I spent the last 2 days trying figure it out, what do I type for read something about the 3 dot?

Comment: @Linus Great :) You'll get a bunch of additional features that you can use if you use a more modern standard, such as C++17 or even C++20. I've added a solution that works in C++14 as well anyway. The `...` syntax is a fold-expression. I've added a link for further reading.

Comment: Thank you very very much, I will read something more about the difference of the standard since now

Comment: @Linus I've added demos for both solutions, in case that might help.

Comment: I saw that, anyway I put both and separated with macros

Comment: @Linus I don't know what you mean, but please don't use macros. They are generally not needed, and they are definitely not needed here.

Comment: something like `#define __cpluscplus == 201402L  [doStuffForC++14] #elif __cpluscplus == 201703L doStuffForC++17] #endif`

Comment: @Linus Oh, I see. Unless you're writing code that may be compile with different versions, this is unnecessary, but it's good to learn how this works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227431/discussion-between-linus-and-cigien).